# Ayuda API de Instagram para obtener fotos de un Hashtag

Tags: php, html5, api

Hola a todos quiero iniciar una app web con el API de Instagram, que me rastree un hashtag y me devuelva las fotos publicadas con el.

Ya revise el API, pero no tengo mucha experiencia usándolo, alguien puede ayudarme? gracias a todos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes descargar un js desde la página [Instafeedjs](http://instafeedjs.com/)

Luego en tu instagram te facilitan un ID de usuario, que usaras en el Javascript de la página. Yo el código que he usado es este

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/instafeed.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var loadButton = document.getElementById('load-more');
var loadButton2 = document.getElementById('load-more2');

feed = new Instafeed({

userId: TU USER ID,
accessToken: 'TU TOKEN',
tagName:'Hastag a buscar',
sortby: 'most-recent',
get: 'tagged',
resolution: 'thumbnail',
links: 'true',
template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;',
limit: 60,

after: function() {
    // disable button if no more results to load
    if (!this.hasNext()) {
      loadButton.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
},
 });
 loadButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
 feed.next();
});

 feed.run();
```

El código HTML es

```
<div id="instafeed"></div>
    <input type="button" id="load-more" name="load-more" class="main" value="Mas fotos">
```